# iPhone/iPad: how to change location of home or cancel or any buttons in UINavigationController (with or without InterfaceBuilder)

Tags: iphone, button, uinavigationcontroller, position, uinavigationbar

My question is fairly straightforward and simple.

I have seen code that implements a button (such as a cancel button) that can be added to a UINavigationController. Code looks like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
        initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"] 
        style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target: self 
        action: @selector(cancel:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
[cancelButton release];
```

What I'd like to do is to place these buttons in a custom location in the navigationItem...not in the default rightBarButtonItem or leftBarButtonItem location, but controllable perhaps using x and y co-ordinates...is this even possible? It seems like a simple request, but google searching and documentation reviewing is driving me a little nuts :)

I would appreciate any assistance with this issue.

thanks again,

Edward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with 'Hack Saw' in the case of it being against the Apple 'Human Interface Guide' and thus not recommended...However... If you want to, you can draw additional views into the navigation bar's title view [self.navigationContoller.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView].  Hope that helps!

Here is link to reference: [UINavigationItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UINavigationItem)

Comment: @Hack saw and Derek H. thanks for your input so far. So if I had to build my own navbar, how would I go about it? Interface Builder? hand code? Also I am actually using it in the iPad in landscape orientation mode, so I don't think apple interface guidelines apply per se...would appreciate your comments on that though - basically using the pad as a touch screen monitor-type device

Comment: Is this going to be a single tool bar, or will it keep track of navigation throughout the application?

Answer (score 1):

They don't make that easy because it would break user expectation. I recommend against it. If you have a serious need for it, you'll probably need to make your own navbar.

Comment: saw and Derek H. thanks for your input so far. So if I had to build my own navbar, how would I go about it? Interface Builder? hand code? Also I am actually using it in the iPad in landscape orientation mode, so I don't think apple interface guidelines apply per se...would appreciate your comments on that though

Comment: Apple tries to make it easiest to do the thing the guidelines suggest. The navbar on the iPad is probably a scaled up version of the one on the iPhone to leverage the iPhone user base's knowledge of the interface. If you have serious design issues with the default, you kind of have to build from the ground up. Make the main bar an IB thing, and then design your buttons in IB as well.

Comment: Then you make sure to connect them to outlets, which will allow you to move them as needed. If there are to be an indeterminate number of buttons, you might need to load the NIB by hand, which you can do multiple times for multiple instances of the same button.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I began investigating the NavigationBar class at developer.apple.com and downloaded the example (shows 5 different, but still apple standard navigation bars) so I am hoping to extrapolate the information from there. I will also take your IB advice as well. cheers